# What CDN for jquery & jquerymobile will offer the best load speed on mobile devices?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cdn

I need to know what CDN for **jquery & jquery-mobile** will offer the best performance in terms of load speed for mobile devices.

There are a few things to take into account such as transfer speed from host to user, probability of the scripts already being cached on devices, and any other issues you can think of.-

Comment: Local hosted files are safer. If jquery server is down, you'll be in trouble.

Comment: wow nice link, thanks +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery CDN are fastest to use. But the server might be down (although I haven't experience this issue), so its suggested you use local files. Also, browsers `cache` the JS files, so JS file won't be fetched every time from the server when you refresh the page. Here are the links to jQuery CDN:

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js

Comment: I am having a problem right now with code.jquery.com taking over 15 seconds to load or failing entirely. I would recommend hosting jquery.mobile yourself, though Google's CDN is great for plain jQuery.